# How to use Perl glob to read remote location?

Tags: perl, glob

my test script:

```
my $loc = "\\\\ant\\d1_sp\\test__18716093";
####$loc = "c:\\temp"; #this works good if I un-comment.
system("dir $loc\\*.log"); #added system command just for debugging.
my @test = glob qq("$loc\\*.log");
print "\narray=@test\n";
```

I want to save the file names in *$loc* into array for further processing, but its not doing so, what am I missing? output is:

```
C:\>perl c:\temp\foo.pl

Directory of \\ant\d1_sp\test__18716093

03/14/2016  01:09 PM               959 build_1.8980.log
03/14/2016  01:20 PM           102,402 build_2.98981.log
           2 File(s)        103,361 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  1,589,522,239,488 bytes free

array=
C:\>
```

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes instead of all those backslashes?

Comment: Can you use a module that will take care of all those for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to list the `.log` files in the following share:

```
\\ant\d1_sp\test__18716093
```

To do so, you need to use the following glob pattern:

```
\\\\ant\\d1_sp\\test__18716093\\*.log
```

The following is a string literal that produces that string:

```
"\\\\\\\\ant\\\\d1_sp\\\\test__18716093\\\\*.log"
```

So the solution is

```
glob("\\\\\\\\ant\\\\d1_sp\\\\test__18716093\\\\*.log")
```

Best to just use `/` instead of `\` since you don't need to escape it in either glob patterns or string literals.

```
glob("//ant/d1_sp/test__18716093/*.log")
```

Comment: shouldn't that be "Best to just use `/` instead of `\\`..."?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use `glob` on a network drive, however `opendir` and `readdir` will work

Like this

```
my $loc = '\\\\ant\d1_sp\test__18716093';

my @test = do {
    opendir my ($dh), $loc or die $!;
    map "$loc\\$_", grep /\.log$/i, readdir $dh;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your `qq` supplies extra quoting that `glob` may or may not handle as intended.

This correctly lists all `.pl` files in `$loc`, being single directory or `'{dir1,dir2,...}'`

```
my @files = glob "$loc/*.pl";
```

With an extra `qq` I get the empty list, on v5.10.

Here is an example with extra `qq` brought up in a comment by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot), copied

```
mkdir foo && touch foo/{bar,baz,qux}.pl;
perl -E '$loc = "foo"; say for glob qq{"$loc/*.pl"}'
# prints `foo/bar.pl, foo/baz.pl, and foo/qux.pl`.
```

This works as intended on v5.16 but on v5.10 it does not (empty list), while without `qq` it does. This inconsistent behavior of `glob` with respect to quoting and space was [fixed in v5.16](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#The-glob-operator).

With spaces in the path an extra level of quoting is necessary, as noted by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) and explained by [ThisSuitIsNotBlack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) in comments, summarized here.
For `$path` with spaces one needs either of

```
$loc = q("$path"); glob("$loc/*");  
$loc = "$path";    glob(qq{"$loc/*"});
```

Another option, which I would prefer, is to use [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~kwilliams/Path-Class-0.36/README.pod).

---

From `perldoc -f glob`:

> This is the internal function implementing the `<*.c>` operator, but you can use it  directly. If EXPR is omitted, `$_` is used.  The `<*.c>` operator is discussed in more detail in "I/O Operators" in perlop.

From `perldoc perlop`, while talking about `<..>`

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple
>       scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob
>       reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed, and
>       either a list of filenames or the next filename in the list is returned,
>       depending on context.
>
> ...
>
> One level of double-quote interpretation is done first...

[No more interpolation is mentioned.]

Comment: Double quotes around a file pattern are fine, and necessary if you have spaces in the path

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect: `mkdir foo && touch foo/{bar,baz,qux}.pl && perl -E'$loc = "foo"; say for glob qq{"$loc/*.pl"}'` prints `foo/bar.pl`, `foo/baz.pl`, and `foo/qux.pl`.

Comment: @zdim Ah, it looks like treatment of quotes in `glob` was inconsistent [until 5.16.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#The-glob-operator). On 5.10.1, `glob(qq{"foo bar/*.pl"})` works because there's a space, but `glob(qq{"foo/*.pl"})` doesn't. The extra quotes are necessary if the path contains any spaces, but you're right that they're unnecessary here.

Comment: @zdim You have to include literal quotes in the glob pattern if your path contains a space. `glob(q{foo bar/*})` returns `foo` followed by the contents of directory `bar`. `glob(q{"foo bar/*"})` returns the contents of directory `foo bar`. That's what Borodin was referring to.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ok, yes it's needed for that.  But isn't that a bit of a hack? I'd rather build my `$loc` carefully -- escape spaces, or use quotes, or best use a module for Windows paths.  Then quote once. It gets dizzying with directly nested quotes. We are talking about `glob qq("$loc")`, where `$loc` has been built somehow.  The `qq` is just extra, to me. I don't want to rely on that to fix my `$loc`.

Comment: It's not a hack, it's required so that `glob` interprets your pattern as one pattern containing a space and not as two separate patterns. At some point you have to embed the literal quotes in your glob pattern, whether you do `my $loc = q{"foo bar"}; glob($loc);` or `my $loc = "foo bar"; glob(qq{"$loc"});` doesn't matter. Alternatively, `use File::Glob qw(:bsd_glob);` will treat spaces in the pattern as part of the filename, so you can just do `my $loc = "foo bar"; glob($loc)`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Thank you, summarized above.