# Get the path for a similarly named file in perl, where only the extension differs?

Tags: perl, glob

I'm trying to write an Automator service, so I can chuck this into a right-click menu in the gui.

I have a filepath to a txt file, and there is a similarly named file that varies only in the file extension. This can be a pdf or a jpg, or potentially any other extension, no way to know beforehand. How can I get the filepath to this other file (there will only be one such)?

```
$other_name =~ s/txt$/!(txt)/;
$other_name =~ s/ /?/g;
my @test = glob "$other_name";
```

In Bash, I'd just turn on the extglob option, and change the "txt" at the end to "!(txt)" and the do glob expansion. But I'm not even sure if that's available in perl. And since the filepaths always have spaces (it's in one of the near-root directory names), that further complicates things. I've read through the glob() documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html and tried every variation of quoting (the above example code shows my attempt after having given up, where I just remove all the spaces entirely).

It seems like I'm able to put modules inside the script, so this doesn't have to be bare perl (just ran a test).

Is there an elegant or at least simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Other than the 3 (or 4) letter extension, the files have the exact same filename, and path. One is txt, the other not.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract everything in the filename up to extension, then run a glob with that and filter out the unneeded .txt. This is one of those cases where you need to protect the pattern in the glob with a double set of quotes, for spaces.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "dir with space/file with spaces.txt";

# Pull the full name without extension
my ($basefname) = $file =~ m/(.*)\.txt$/;

# Get all files with that name and filter out unneeded (txt)
my @other_exts = grep { not /\.txt$/ } glob(qq{"$basefname.*"});

say for @other_exts;
```

With a toy structure like this

```
dir space/
file with spaces.pdf
file with spaces.txt
```

The output is

```
dir space/file with spaces.pdf
```

---

This [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999388/how-to-use-perl-glob-to-read-remote-location/36000203#36000203) has more on related globs.

Answer (score 2):

Perl doesn't allow the *not substring* construct in glob. You have to find all files with the same name and any extension, and remove the one ending with `.txt`

This program shows the idea. It splits the original file name into a stem part and a suffix part, and uses the stem to form a glob pattern. The `grep` removes any result that ends with the original suffix

It picks only the first matching file name if there is more than one candidate. `$other_name` will be set to `undef` if no matching file was found

The original file name is expected as a parameter on the command line

The result is printed to STDOUT; I don't know what you need for your right-click menu

The line `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'` is necessary if you are working with file paths that contain spaces, as it seems you are

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';

my ($stem, $suffix) = shift =~ /(.*)(\..*)/;

my ($other_name) = grep ! /$suffix$/i, glob "$stem.*";
$other_name =~ tr/ /?/;

print $other_name, "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an example, based on [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) core module

```
use File::Basename;

my $fullname = "/path/to/my/filename.txt";
my ($name, $path, $suffix) = fileparse($fullname, qw/.txt/);
my $new_filename = $path . $name . ".pdf";

# $name         --> filename
# $path         --> /path/to/my/
# $suffix       --> .txt
# $new_filename --> /path/to/my/filename.pdf
```

Comment: This won't work. I don't know that the second file will be "pdf". Could be anything (other than txt).

Comment: If this were all that was required, you could write simply `my $new_filename = $fullname =~ s/\.txt$/.pdf/`